# How do you create the 64bit hash used by the C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository?

Tags: winapi, driver, windows-driver

Does anyone know how to calculate the hash used in the Windows driver store?  For example, `vsmraid.inf_amd64_3d2bbc45931b8232`.   I'm sure it's some portion of the .inf, but does anyone have the answer?

Thanks.

Comment: The only information I can find is that the INF contains a reference to a CAT catalog file, which in turn contains a cryptographic hash of every file the driver uses, including the INF. There is no information about how the hashes are created, which makes sense so that people can't freely mess around with them. Why do you need to know this information? What are you planning on doing with the hashes? Microsoft has tools for creating catalog files and verifying driver integrity, so I don't see a use case where you need to calculate the hashes manually.

Comment: I actually know how to create a .cat file from scratch, but not sure the hash used for the driverstore, it's to support new features of .inf files in the driver store.  I didn't check if they used the same one, it's been a while since I worked on that stuff.